# Counting field by day in mssql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table with Scheduling slots called:

ScheduleSlots

Fields:
id (int)
scheduleID (int)
time (datetime)
availableslots (int)
CalendarGroupID (int)
Level (int)
enabled (bit)

I want to setup a gridview where I take all of the dates and count enabled and disabled for each day.
I am not sure how to go about writing the sql statement to do this.

ie.
Date        Enabled    Disabled
3/31/2021   20         20
4/1/2021    10         30

```
SELECT Time, scheduleID,
(SELECT COUNT(Enabled) FROM [dbo].[ScheduleSlots] 
WHERE Cast(Time as Date)>='2021-03-31' AND Cast(Time as Date)<='2021-04-01' AND CalendarGroupID=1 AND Level=1 AND Enabled=1) as Enabled, 
(SELECT COUNT(Enabled) FROM [dbo].[ScheduleSlots] 
WHERE Cast(Time as Date)>='2021-03-31' AND Cast(Time as Date)<='2021-04-01' AND CalendarGroupID=1 AND Level=1 AND Enabled=0) as Disabled
FROM [dbo].[ScheduleSlots] 
WHERE Cast(Time as Date)>='2021-03-31' AND Cast(Time as Date)<='2021-04-01' AND CalendarGroupID=1 AND Level=1
GROUP BY scheduleID, Time
```

The results I end up with:
[Results][1]

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without inner selects:

```
SELECT [Time],
    SUM([Enabled]) as [Enabled], 
    SUM([Disabled]) as [Disabled]
FROM [dbo].[ScheduleSlots] 
WHERE 
    [Time]>='2021-03-31' 
    AND [Time]<='2021-04-01'
    AND CalendarGroupID=1 
    AND Level=1
GROUP BY Cast([Time] as Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an easy grouping query:

```sql
SELECT 
  CONVERT(DATE, "Time") AS "Date", 
  SUM(CONVERT(INT, "Enabled")) AS "Enabled",
  COUNT() - SUM(CONVERT(INT, "Enabled")) AS "Disabled"
FROM "dbo"."ScheduleSlots"
WHERE "CalendarGroupID" = 1 
  AND "Level" = 1
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, "Time")
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly where you want the enable slot and diable slot for each day.

```
;With CTE(Transdate) as (Select Distinct([time]) from ScheduleSlots) 
Select CTE.Transdate,(Select COUNT(Id) from ScheduleSlots where enabled= 1 
and Transdate = CTE.Transdate) as Enable,
(Select COUNT(Id) from ScheduleSlots where enabled= 0 
and Transdate = CTE.Transdate) as Disable from CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

I inserted some records to make it clear. If I am wrong with inserted data please send me the insert scripts so, that I can test the results.
CREATE TABLE ScheduleSlots
(
id  int,
scheduleID int,
[time] datetime,
availableslots int,
CalendarGroupID int,
[Level] int,
[enabled] bit

```
)

 ----insert into  ScheduleSlots values(1,1,'2021-03-31',40,1,1,20) 
 INSERT INTO  ScheduleSlots VALUES(1,1,'2021-03-31',20,1,1,0) 
 INSERT INTO  ScheduleSlots VALUES(1,1,'2021-03-31',20,1,1,1) 
 INSERT INTO  ScheduleSlots VALUES(1,1,'2021-03-31',20,1,1,1) 
 INSERT INTO  ScheduleSlots VALUES(1,1,'2021-04-01',40,1,1,1) 
 INSERT INTO  ScheduleSlots VALUES(1,1,'2021-04-01',40,1,1,0) 

SELECT DISTINCT
   [time] AS [Date]
   ,SUM(availableslots) OVER(PARTITION BY [time] ORDER BY  [time]) AS [avaibale] 
    ,SUM(CAST([enabled] AS INT)) OVER(PARTITION BY [time] ORDER BY  [time]) AS [Enabled] 
   ,SUM(availableslots) OVER(PARTITION BY [time] ORDER BY  [time]) - 
    SUM(CAST([enabled] AS INT)) OVER(PARTITION BY [time] ORDER BY  [time])  AS  [Disabled] 
 FROM ScheduleSlots
```

Answer I got:
[image: Result]